# CSS checkbox event not working

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to overlay the page with a div (which be used for a menu), when the checkbox button is checked, but it doesn't seem to work. Is the event not firing?

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7e6w0Lcv/4/).

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <div id="topBar"></div>
    <div id="menuTab"><input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle">&equiv;</div>
</nav>

<section>
    <div id="slide1" class="slide">
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#menuToggle {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}
input#menuToggle:checked + #menuOverlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.95;
    z-index: 3;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    input#menuToggle:checked + #menuOverlay {
        background:#000;
        height:100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    input#menuToggle:checked + #menuOverlay {
        background:#1f1f1f;
        height:2.4em;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `#menuOverlay`

Comment: Please include your Javascript as well or post this to JSFiddle.net so we can see it not working and fix it.

Comment: Then, someone remove the wrong tags, please...

Comment: Question updated with fiddle

Comment: Yeah, you would have to use javascript for this.

Comment: @KJPrice why would you need JS?

Comment: Based on your question, I'm assuming you're missing the javascript code that should create an overlay element when the checkbox is checked (and remove it when it unchecked).

Comment: The javascript is not missing -- this needs no javascript, it is done in pure CSS.

Comment: @Shahar no JS code is needed.

Comment: @epascarello I see... using the checkbox to toggle overlay, nice. +1 for simplicity (and not using js)

Comment: Is `<div id=slide1` to be `<div id=menuOverlay`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not using correct `+` selector.

> B + E:    Any E element that is the next sibling of a B element (that is:
>   the next child of the same parent)

You don't have any element with id `#menuOverlay` at all in DOM.

The only way this will work with your current css is the following:

```css
#menuToggle {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}
#menuToggle:checked + #menuOverlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.95;
    z-index: 3;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    input#menuToggle:checked + #menuOverlay {
        background:#000;
        height:100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    input#menuToggle:checked + #menuOverlay {
        background:#1f1f1f;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="topBar"></div>
    <div id="menuTab">
        <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle" />&equiv;
        <div id="menuOverlay"></div> <!-- add div element here with id menuOverlay -->
    </div>
</nav>
<section>
    <div id="slide1" class="slide"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whit the menuOverlay properly added :

http://jsfiddle.net/e230cpwz/1/

```
<div id="menuTab"><input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle" />&equiv;
    <div id="menuOverlay" >
    </div>
</div>
```